# How do I update a custom theme

Tags: updates

I have a custom theme that I use for many client sites. I regularly update the theme and need a way to have the sites notified when there is an update to the theme.

I tried using https://github.com/UCF/Theme-Updater but since it is no longer supported and hasn't been updated I can not get it to work with WP 4.1.1.

I get the notification of the update in WP, but the update will not load. I get an error every time.

Is there another way to update custom themes?

Comment: See this [related question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16093/making-update-notification-functionality-for-my-themes). Chip Bennett's answer seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: I may be late to the party, but you can find a plugin I built exactly for that: [WP Plugin Update Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-plugin-update-server/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full documentation for how to do this:
[Github updater - Documentation](https://github.com/afragen/github-updater)

**Upload in wordpress**

Download the latest tagged archive (choose the "[**zip**](https://github.com/afragen/github-updater/archive/develop.zip)" option).

Unzip the archive, rename the folder correctly to ***github-updater***, then ***re-zip*** the file.

Go to the Plugins -> Add New screen and click the Upload tab.

Upload the zipped archive directly.

Go to the Plugins screen and click Activate.

[**Description**]

This plugin was designed to simply update any GitHub hosted WordPress
 plugin or theme. Your plugin or theme must contain a header in the
 style.css header or in the plugin's header denoting the location on
 GitHub. The format is as follows.

`GitHub Plugin URI: afragen/github-updater`

`GitHub Plugin URI: https://github.com/afragen/github-updater`

or

`GitHub Theme URI: afragen/test-child`

`GitHub Theme URI: https://github.com/afragen/test-child`

...where the above URI leads to the **owner/repository** of your theme or
 plugin. The URI may be in the format `https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>`
 or the short format `<owner>/<repo>`. You do not need both. Only one
 Plugin or Theme URI is required. **You must not** include any extensions
 like `.git`.

**[Usage]**

**Plugins**

There must be a `GitHub Plugin URI`, `Bitbucket Plugin URI`, or `GitLab Plugin URI` declaration in the plugin's header.

```
/*
Plugin Name:       GitHub Updater
Plugin URI:        https://github.com/afragen/github-updater
Description:       A plugin to automatically update GitHub, Bitbucket or GitLab hosted plugins and themes. It also allows for remote installation of plugins or themes into WordPress.
Version:           1.0.0
Author:            Andy Fragen
License:           GNU General Public License v2
License URI:       http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Domain Path:       /languages
Text Domain:       github-updater
GitHub Plugin URI: https://github.com/afragen/github-updater
GitHub Branch:     master
*/
```

**Themes**

There must be a `GitHub Theme URI`, `Bitbucket Theme URI`, or `GitLab Theme URI` declaration in the `style.css` file. When initially adding a theme, the directory **must** be identical to the repo name.

```
/*
Theme Name:       Test
Theme URI:        http://thefragens.net/
Version:          0.1.0
Description:      Child theme of TwentyTwelve.
Author:           Andy Fragen
Template:         twentytwelve
Template Version: 1.0.0
GitHub Theme URI: https://github.com/afragen/test-child
GitHub Branch:    master
*/
```

Hope this helps.

Please let me know

Comment: Hi @Dionoh - thanks for posting an answer, but please include more detail: answers with just links are very fragile. When the link dies, your answer becomes useless, so try to include as much detail as possible (even if it's not complete, but only enough for a reader to base further research on)

Comment: Just did it.

Is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple solution that you don't have to worry about coding yourself I would recommend you check out [wp-updates.com](http://wp-updates.com/).

I think it's free to signup for an account, it works for both custom themes and custom plugins, and they claim you can integrate the service with just *2 lines* of code.

> Provide automatic updates for your premium WordPress themes and plugins with 2 lines of code.

It's made by the team at [Dev7studios](http://dev7studios.com/), who are a respected group in the premium WordPress plugin space.

Good luck!